# Creating a native browser login using meteor/jQuery

Tags: ajax, jquery, meteor, basic-authentication

I would like to prompt a native login for my admin page (something like this http://demo2.opencrypt.com/oc/members/).

I'm aware that most like I have to use $.ajax and force it to response statusCode 401. However, I have no idea how I should proceed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am not absolutly sure but I think if you want to handle a basic auth you cannot let the user show that form by your own. That comes directly from the webserver however if you just need to auth for that ajax request you could try to use this schema:

```
http://user:password@server/path/to/file
```

While you need to handle that username and password somehow yourself.